# SharePoint Online - Javascript Bundling

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

My Application is hosted using SharePoint Online. To improve performance, JavaScript bundling is implemented. Issue is, Application related JavaScript files are bundled but JavaScript files related to SharePoint needs to be bundled. Do we have any option in SharePoint Online.

Sample list of SharePoint Online Related JavaScript files,

```
/_layouts/15/16.0.6223.1208/sp.ui.dialog.js
/_layouts/15/16.0.6223.1208/sp.taxonomy.js
/_layouts/15/16.0.6223.1208/sp.search.js
/_layouts/15/16.0.6223.1208/sp.userprofiles.js
```

Comment: Would performance be an issue if you are using SOD or RequireJS? A little more on each at http://www.migee.com/2015/09/24/understanding-sharepoint-and-script-on-demand-sod/comment-page-1/ and https://medium.com/@ankitgirgas/how-to-use-sharepoint-native-require-js-for-loading-modules-41b683ed73a5

Answer (score 0):

When working with the SharePoint Framework we can however choose whether we want to have our dependencies bundled together with Web Parts or not.

Have a look on excellent [Link](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/bundling-external-frameworks-sharepoint-framework-client-side-web-parts-bad-idea/)

"@microsoft/sp-client-base": "node_modules/@microsoft/sp-client-base/dist/sp-client-base.js",
    "@microsoft/sp-client-preview": "node_modules/@microsoft/sp-client-preview/dist/sp-client-preview.js",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "node_modules/@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset/dist/sp-lodash-subset.js",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "node_modules/office-ui-fabric-react/dist/office-ui-fabric-react.js",